# Compact self-adjoint orthogonal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $x,y$ are self-adjoint compact linear operators acting in $H$. If $x^2\cdot y^2 =0$ then is it true that $x\cdot y=0$?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $x\cdot y$, if $x, y$ are linear operators? (BTW, I think that capital letters would be a more common notation for operators)

Comment: By $x\cdot y$ I mean the composition operator i.e. $(x\cdot y)(h)=x(y(h))$ for all $h\in H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a selfadjoint operator on a Hilbert space, then $X^2x=0$ iff $Xx=0$ because $X^2x=0\implies 0=\langle X^2x,x\rangle = \langle Xx,Xx\rangle=\|Xx\|^2$.

Therefore, if $X,Y$ are selfadjoint and $X^2Y^2=0$, it follows that $XY^2=0$. Taking adjoints gives $Y^2X=0$ and, hence, $YX=0$. Taking adjoints again gives the desired result that $XY=0$.

Comment: Actually, you are using the implication $X^2T=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $XT=0$ for self-adjoint $X$ and arbitrary $T$.Took me a while...

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT**. This counterexample cannot be self-adjoint (see comment). Therefore this answer is wrong.

It is false, consider $x=y$ and let $x$ be any operator such that $x^2\ne 0$ and $x^4=0$ (you can make an explicit $4\times 4$ matrix example).

Comment: If $X$ is selfadjoint, then $\mathcal{N}(X)=\mathcal{N}(X^2)$ because $X^2x=0$ implies $0 =\langle X^2x,x\rangle = \langle Xx,Xx\rangle=\|Xx\|^2$. It is this property which guarantees that the minimal polynomial of a selfadjoint matrix has only linear factors, and that gives a diagonalization.

Comment: Oh right, I completely overlooked the selfadjointness assumption

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: my previous comment was addressed to you

Comment: I +1'd the comment as my way of acknowledging it. :)